# Simple CSS image cross-fading acting weird

Tags: css, image, slideshow, transition, fading

I am trying to create a very simple image cross fade effect with four different pictures. It should go smoothly from 1st to the 2nd, from 2nd to 3rd, 3rd to 4th and then back to the 1st.

This is the code I am using:

HTML:

```
    <div class="css-slideshow"> 
      <figure> 
            <img src="test1.jpg"/> 
      </figure> 
      <figure> 
            <img src="test2.jpg"/> 
      </figure>
      <figure> 
            <img src="test3.jpg" /> 
      </figure>
      <figure> 
            <img src="test4.jpg" /> 
      </figure>  
    </div>
```

...and CSS:

```
    figure:nth-child(1) {
       -webkit-animation: xfade 12s 9s infinite;
    }
    figure:nth-child(2) {
       -webkit-animation: xfade 12s 6s infinite;
    }
    figure:nth-child(3) {
       -webkit-animation: xfade 12s 3s infinite;
    }
    figure:nth-child(4) {
       -webkit-animation: xfade 12s 0s infinite;
    }


    @-webkit-keyframes xfade{
     0%   { opacity:1; }
     19%  { opacity:1; }
     25%  { opacity:0; }
     94%  { opacity:0; }
     100% { opacity:1; }
    }
```

The idea is the whole sequence should take 12 seconds.

The first loop looks great, the transitions are smooth, everything works like a charm. However, with the start of the second, and any other loop, it looks like it's not fading directly to the next image, but sort of through the white background. You can spot a "flash" while fading.

Can you help me? I am guessing the problem lays somewhere in that percentage, but I'm not sure.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the first iteration is different than the others is that initially all the images have opacity 1. (The initial value for the elements)
In the following iterations, they are transparent (the value given by the animation)

Check it here, adding a small offset so that what I say is visible.

```css
figure {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

figure:nth-child(1) {
   -webkit-animation: xfade 12s 9s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(2) {
    top: 20px;
   -webkit-animation: xfade 12s 6s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(3) {
    top: 40px;
   -webkit-animation: xfade 12s 3s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(4) {
    top: 60px;
   -webkit-animation: xfade 12s 0s infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes xfade{
  0% { opacity:1; }
  19% { opacity:1; }
  25% { opacity:0; }
  94% { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="css-slideshow"> 
          <figure> 
                <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/golf_woman_tee_216208.jpg"/> 
          </figure> 
          <figure> 
                <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/picture_of_the_golf_11_168191.jpg"/> 
          </figure>
          <figure> 
                <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/golf_picture_3_168179.jpg" /> 
          </figure> 
          <figure> 
                <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/picture_of_the_evening_under_the_golf_course_168171.jpg" /> 
          </figure> 
    </div>
```

How to fix it :

1. Set the animation delay with negative values. This way, the first iteration will be the same as the others
2. Close the gap between fade-out of one element and fade-in of the following. This is acomplished changing the percentages in the keyframes

```css
figure {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
   -webkit-animation: xfade 12s infinite;
}

figure:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3s;
}
figure:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6s;
}
figure:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9s;
}
figure:nth-child(4) {
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes xfade{
  0% { opacity:1; }
  30% { opacity:1; }
  40% { opacity:0; }
  90% { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="css-slideshow"> 
          <figure> 
                <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/golf_woman_tee_216208.jpg"/> 
          </figure> 
          <figure> 
                <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/picture_of_the_golf_11_168191.jpg"/> 
          </figure>
          <figure> 
                <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/golf_picture_3_168179.jpg" /> 
          </figure> 
          <figure> 
                <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/picture_of_the_evening_under_the_golf_course_168171.jpg" /> 
          </figure> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this tutorial carefully (guessing you got your code from there):

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3

That should completely answer your question.  I know this tutorial accomplishes what you're trying to do (cross-browser as well, if you pull the more-complete CSS from the actual demo for it).

Answer (score 0):

Its an optical illusion, your code works fine.

There's a term for this exact illusion however I do not remember what it is.

> When an object changes in our peripheral vision, it is interpreted as a sudden flash to obtain our immediate attention to this "spontaneous appearance".

If you cover either the disappearing or the appearing image with your hand then it will look like a perfectly smooth animation. You also must have your attention on where the image is appearing for the illusion to not take place.

The reason the first iteration 'looks' fine is because nothing is `appearing` thus the optical illusion doesn't occur!

Comment: Haha, sorry, but absolutely NOT. First iteration is exactly the same as the others, first image getting smoothly replaced with the second, and so on, with no white gap between them. I actually print screened it and yes, at one point during the fading, it gets transparent, making it look a lot more "white", causing that bad looking flash (which is unacceptable in my situation). However, djvs's answer seems promising, but I'll take a look at it tomorrow. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah well my apologies, would be nice if you had a fiddle to show this. I plugged your code in (with empty images) and it looks fine.

Comment: Sorry, here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/jmwycapu/ I forgot to mention that the figure should have an absolute position, causing the pictures to fade directly into themselves, in the same position, I believed it was clear from the text, sorry. Anyway, you can see a slight "flashes" in any other then first iteration. It's not that bad in this example, but in my specific one (full-screen background picture with mostly dark colors) it is extremely noticeable.